# (Excel) Adding a specific number with decimal point before other values

Tags: excel, numbers, decimal, point

I would like to know how can I put a specific number with decimal point before other values in Excel?

For example: my first value in the column is 6,123 (number). Next values are entered as **text**, such as: 124, 125, 126 etc.

Now I need to add "6," before every of the other values, so the end result to be: 6,124; 6,125...

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: either do it directly as text like `="6,"&A2` and copy down, or (to avoid problems with `,` and `.`) `=6+A2/10^LEN(A2)` to get a real number...

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONCATENATE()` function to prefix `6,` to your numbers.  Have a look at the screen capture below to see how to do this:

[image]

Note that you may have to cast the `B` column to numeric type as well.

Comment: Here is what problem it gives me when I use the function (http://imgur.com/Tc2yEPS)

And here is the actual table content: http://imgur.com/jvIrdEQ

Comment: Are you sure you entered the _exact_ formula from my answer?

Comment: Yes, I entered the exact formula and it showed me that problem. 

The answer from Dirk Reichel worked for me. Thank you too!